IIS 500.19 0x8007000d error, but API calls are successful when calling from postman
Web application: C# API, Angular frontend.
On one specific machine i'm getting error IIS 500.19 0x8007000d when trying to access web application via angular frontend. All config files are fine, and are exactly the same as on other machines on which application is working fine.
Interesting part is, that when on this problematic machine i'm calling API via postman, the API is responding 200 OK, and everything seems to be working fine, which is weird because with this IIS error, backend shouldn't even be running..
Maybe anyone has encountered that issue?
Thanks.

could you share detailed error snapshot? and web.config file. make sure if you are using url rewrite ule you have install url rewrite module in problematic machine. Set iis_iusrs and iusr permission to the iis site root folder.
